# React Native style textDecorationLine: 'underline' is not working in iOS 13

Tags: react-native

I am trying to render multiline text *Eg. This is my text **Read more***, where for '**Read more**' I am applying a style `textDecorationLine: 'underline'`. It works fine on Android. But in iOS 13, it works only if the underline text is not in the first line.

[image: Refer the screenshot]

I tried to wrap this text in `View`, but I have to render this text at the end of a text that is obtained from the Server. Any solution?

```js
<Text
  style={{
    fontSize: 12,
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    marginHorizontal: 10,
  }}
>
  {text}
  <Text
    style={{
      textDecorationLine: "underline",
      textDecorationStyle: "solid",
    }}
    onPress={() => {
      this.readMore();
    }}
  >
    Read more
  </Text>
</Text>
```

Comment: Please add your Code

Comment: @Tim I have added the code.

Comment: Can you try to do this with a native app and see if this is still happening?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the color for your text component.

```js
<Text
     style={{
              textDecorationLine: 'underline',
              textDecorationStyle: 'solid',
              textDecorationColor: "red",
           }}
        whatever your text
</Text>
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and just found out that this has nothing to do with React Native. It is a font glitch which is also there when you show the font with underline in a native application. It is also unrelated to iOS 13 since it also happens with iOS 11. Though there is a difference between React Native and iOS.

This is the Balto font in React Native:

[image]

This is the Balto font in native:

[image]

Used font specs:

- Family: Balto
- Size: 19
- Weight: Bold
- Style: underline